# Tic Tac Toe Game: TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment when trying to change letter to upper case

Tags: python, dictionary, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a tic tac toe game just to assimilate better the concepts i'm learning with python programing.

At a point in my code, i'm trying to do a character substitution to a upper case letter, because the user can either put "meio-E" or "meio-e" but i keep geeting the error "TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment"

Here's the part i'm trying to change:

```
# Função que coloca as peças X no tabuleiro
def coloca_pecas_X(tabuleiro):
    desenha_tabuleiro(o_tabuleiro)
    print("Faça sua Jogada (topo, meio, baixo)-(E, M, D). Ex: topo-M")
    jogada = input()
    jogada[-1] = jogada[-1].upper()
    
    tabuleiro[jogada] = " X "
```

The full error message is as it goes:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Usuário\Documents\Curso Python\jogo_da_veia.py", line 65, in <module>
    proxJogada()
  File "D:\Usuário\Documents\Curso Python\jogo_da_veia.py", line 57, in proxJogada
    coloca_pecas_X(o_tabuleiro)
  File "D:\Usuário\Documents\Curso Python\jogo_da_veia.py", line 33, in coloca_pecas_X
    jogada[-1] = jogada[-1].upper()
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I'll be grateful if someone could help me.

The full code:

```
# Jogo da velha
# Autor: Arthur Silva
# Data: 11/08/2020

o_tabuleiro = {
    "topo-E": "  ",
    "topo-M": "  ",
    "topo-D": "  ",
    "meio-E": "  ",
    "meio-M": "  ",
    "meio-D": "  ",
    "baixo-E": "  ",
    "baixo-M": "  ",
    "baixo-D": "  ",
}

# Função que desenha o tabuleiro
def desenha_tabuleiro(tabuleiro):
    print(tabuleiro["topo-E"] + "|" + tabuleiro["topo-M"] + "|" + tabuleiro["topo-D"])
    print("--------")
    print(tabuleiro["meio-E"] + "|" + tabuleiro["meio-M"] + "|" + tabuleiro["meio-D"])
    print("--------")
    print(
        tabuleiro["baixo-E"] + "|" + tabuleiro["baixo-M"] + "|" + tabuleiro["baixo-D"]
    )


# Função que coloca as peças X no tabuleiro
def coloca_pecas_X(tabuleiro):
    desenha_tabuleiro(o_tabuleiro)
    print("Faça sua Jogada (topo, meio, baixo)-(E, M, D). Ex: topo-M")
    jogada = input()
    jogada[-1] = jogada[-1].upper()
    
    tabuleiro[jogada] = " X "
    desenha_tabuleiro(o_tabuleiro)
    print("\n\n\n\n")


# Função que coloca as peças O no tabuleiro
def coloca_pecas_O(tabuleiro):
    desenha_tabuleiro(o_tabuleiro)
    print("Faça sua Jogada (topo, meio, baixo)-(E, M, D). Ex: topo-M")
    jogada = input()
    jogada[-1] = jogada[-1].upper()
    
    tabuleiro[jogada] = " O "
    desenha_tabuleiro(o_tabuleiro)
    print("\n\n\n\n")


def proxJogada():
    contador = 1
    while contador == 1 or contador == -1:
        if contador == 1:
            print("Sua vez, X")
            coloca_pecas_X(o_tabuleiro)
            contador = contador * -1
        else:
            print("Sua vez, O")
            coloca_pecas_O(o_tabuleiro)
            contador = contador * -1


proxJogada()
```

Pls note that the note is not complete yet, as i'm expecting to eliminate this doubt.

Comment: You can't modify a string. You must create a new string with the changed character.

Answer (score 0):

String is a non-modificable object.

But you could use, instead of trying to change a char, something like:

```
str = "lA lEchCe"

str = str.lower()
```

So, change the entire String.